Statistics for ratios to wildtype growth
I have a large dataset that represents a library of yeast deletion mutants and their growth under treatment from a compound. In the library alongside the mutants is a wild-type strain and I want to express each mutants response to treatment as a ratio to the WT response in order to highlight mutants that show abnormal sensitivity to the compound (hyper-sensitive or resistant) . So far I have settled on a formula to calculate the ratios but am struggling to think of a way to test for significance of results.
For example (not actual data, just for demonstration of data structure):

where I am calculating corrected ratio as:
((growth of mutant treated)/(growth of WT treated))/((growth of mutant at control)/(growth of WT at control))

i.e correcting the ratios with treatment to account for difference in growth at control condition
This then allows me to define sensitivity as corrected ratio<1 and resistance as >1
Is there a way to incorporate a simple statistical test into this to highlight ratios that show significant difference from the WT (where the ratio will always equate to 1)? I have replicates for each mutant and WT (typically N=4) so can easily calcutae SD/SEM etc.

See this answer on Stats.SE for an appropriate significance test. Unfortunately, it's not 'simple', in that you'd have to implement it yourself - I don't know of any software that has it built-in - and you'd also have to modify it to be two-sided. The plus side is, because it's a permutation test, it's appropriate for your small sample sizes, unlike most parametric tests.
